# concept of matrix multiplication and linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

To know my question, I want to share my understanding of matrix multiplication.
let us consider two $3 \times 3$ matrix A and B,
i.e.

\begin{equation*}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}& a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}& a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32}& a_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and \begin{equation*}
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12}& b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22}& b_{23} \\
b_{31} & b_{32}& b_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
also as I know the rows of A are $(a_{11} , a_{12}, a_{13}) $,  $(a_{21} , a_{22}, a_{23}) $ and  $(a_{31} , a_{32}, a_{33}) $ and simillarly for matrix B.
and matrix multiplication of A and B is AB,

\begin{equation*}
AB
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{13}b_{32} & a_{11}b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13}b_{33}\\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}+a_{23}b_{31} & a_{21}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22}+a_{23}b_{32} & a_{21}b_{13}+a_{22}b_{23}+a_{23}b_{33}\\
a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31} & a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{13}b_{32} & a_{11}b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13}b_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

My confusion here is in matrix AB, In my view, the rows of AB are looking like a linear combination of columns of matrix B and coefficients are from matrix A. I define it like for matrix A above.
But somewhere I found that rows of AB are the linear combination of B and coefficient are from matrix A. But I can't understand this please help me to understand it.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first row can be written as the following:
\begin{align}
(a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{21}+a_{13}b_{31}, a_{11}b_{12}+a_{12}b_{22}+a_{13}b_{32}, a_{11}b_{13}+a_{12}b_{23}+a_{13}b_{33})
& = a_{11}(b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{13})+a_{12}(b_{21}, b_{22}, b_{23}) + a_{13}(b_{31}, b_{32}, b_{33})
\end{align}

Comment: okay now I get this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With your notation, if we also denote by $A= \begin{pmatrix}a_1\\ a_2\\ a_3\end{pmatrix}$ the rows of $A$, and $B= \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\ b_2\\ b_3\end{pmatrix}$ the rows of $B$, that is $a_1= \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\end{pmatrix}, b_2= \begin{pmatrix} b_{21} &b_{22} & b_{23}\end{pmatrix}$, etc. We have
$$
AB= \begin{pmatrix} a_{11}b_1+ a_{12}b_2+ a_{13}b_3\\ a_{21}b_1+ a_{22}b_2+ a_{23}b_3\\ a_{31}b_1+ a_{32}b_2+ a_{33}b_3\end{pmatrix},
$$
thus the rows of $AB$ are linear combinations of rows of $B$.

Comment: here A is (3 * 1) and B is also (3*1), how these matrices can be multiplied?

Comment: I don't understand this matrix multiplication and notation in $a_1$ and $a_{11}$.

Comment: So $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the rows of $A$, so they are $1\times 3$ matrices themselves.